# SVG <symbol>s refX/refX attribute and placing a <symbol> relative to its center

Tags: svg, browser

According to SVG's [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol) documentation, I can add the [refX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/refX)/[refY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/refY) attributes to it.

If I understand correctly, I can use these attributes to define a reference point in the symbol's coordinate system so when I reference it with `<use>` element, it will be placed relative to that reference point (instead of the default upper left corner).

But these attributes don't seem to do that or have any effect on the symbol's placement at all. I can't find any additional information about these attributes (for symbol) or whether they are supported in any browser.

Is this how refX/refY actually suppose to work? Are they implemented in any browsers?

If not, Is there any other way to place a symbol with `<use>` element relative to the symbol's center without knowing/calculating its actual width/height in advance?

Comment: No browser supports them, as you've discovered

Comment: Yeah, but I was not sure I understand the docs correctly or use them properly.

Comment: How can you use something that no browser has implemented?

Comment: How could I know they were not implemented? It isn't mentioned anywhere (the refX/refY for <marker> do seem to work despite the fact support for those is not mentioned anywhere as well). So I thought I was missing something.

Comment: Markers had refx and refy in svg 1. They were only proposed for symbols for svg 2.

Comment: @RobertLongson the question is about symbols in svg2

Comment: @danielv FWIW I too came here after reading about this feature in the docs and assuming it was real. this is what we get for RTFM 

Answer (score 7):

I also found that the refX and refY don't work with the symbols. I did find a workaround to effectively do the same thing though. The key is setting the symbol "overflow" variable equal to "visible". The insertion point of the symbol, when using the "use" function, is the always the origin (0,0 coordinate) of the symbols coordinate system, so you simply have to set your symbol up in a way that makes the symbols origin on top of the point where you would like to insert it. I found it easies to do this using a transform because you simply need to use the negative values for the insertion point you want.

Example of making the insertion point the center of a square:

```
<symbol id="test" overflow="visible" >
   <g transform="translate(-50 -50)" >
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" stroke="black"/>
   </g>
</symbol>
```